# object reference not set to an instance of an object while accessing method c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to access InitializeWithFile method from Form2 to Form1 .Form1 is my starting form.

In FORM1:

```
Form2 f2;

public Form1(Form2 _f2)
{
    f2 = _f2;
    StringA = @"D://abc.csv";
    InitializeComponent();
    string s = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {
        csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(StringA);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = csvData;
        //var f = new Form2();
        _f2.InitializeWithFile(StringA);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    return;
}

public Form1()
    : this(null)
{

}
```

In FORM2:

```
public void InitializeWithFile(string csFileName)
{
    StreamReader hGetCommaDelimiterGrid = new StreamReader(csFileName);

    m_arycsFullData.Clear();
    m_arycsFilteredData.Clear();

    m_arycsLogsExcluded.Clear();
    m_arycsLogsIncluded.Clear();

    m_arycsSidesExcluded.Clear();
    m_arycsSidesIncluded.Clear();

    m_arycsMainCodesExcluded.Clear();
    m_arycsMainCodesIncluded.Clear();
    m_arycsMinorCodesExcluded.Clear();
    m_arycsMinorCodesIncluded.Clear();

    while (bReadingFile)
    {
        bReadingFile = Convert.ToBoolean(hGetCommaDelimiterGrid.ReadToEnd());
        if (bReadingFile)
        {
            csCell = GetFilteredData(iRow, SORT_COLUMN_LOG);

            //AddOptionsText(SORT_INDEX_LOG,csCell);
            AddIncludedText(SORT_INDEX_LOG, csCell, true);

            csCell = GetFilteredData(iRow, SORT_COLUMN_SIDE);
            //AddOptionsText(SORT_INDEX_SIDE,csCell);
            AddIncludedText(SORT_INDEX_SIDE, csCell, true);

            csCell = GetFilteredData(iRow, SORT_COLUMN_MAIN_CODE);
            //AddOptionsText(SORT_INDEX_MAIN_CODE,csCell);
            AddIncludedText(SORT_INDEX_MAIN_CODE, csCell, true);

            csCell = GetFilteredData(iRow, SORT_COLUMN_MINOR_CODE);
            //AddOptionsText(SORT_INDEX_MINOR_CODE,csCell);
            AddIncludedText(SORT_INDEX_MINOR_CODE, csCell, true);
        }
        iRow++;
    }
    }
```

And CStdioFile equivalent in c#??????

Comment: If Form1 is your starting form, as you say, then how are you passing an instantiated Form2 into its constructor?  Is there code you can show us that calls Form1?  I'm wondering if your "Form2" is not instantiated correctly. ALSO, are you able to attach a debugger and step through the code? If so, which line throws the error?

Comment: _f2.InitializeWithFile(StringA); at this line i am getting _f2 is null

Comment: There is another way for doing this? Means access form2 method from form1?

Comment: OK, well if _f2 is null, then you can't call _f2.(anything).  I missed the line `public Form1() : this(null)`. Since this is your start form, that is what is being called and so _f2 will always be null and so you can't use it.

Comment: Is there is another way for access method from form2 to form1?

Comment: Dilip Suvagiya suggested a static method in Form2. That will work, assuming you aren't using any nonstatic class variables in Form2.  However, I'm guessing all those m_arycs* variables will mess that up for you. Am I right? Speaking of... what are those lines doing? What are you clearing and why?

Comment: Those are non static.So they giving error like an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property

Comment: So after reading through this again, it looks like what you are trying to do is have your start-up form set up a second form and then have it (form1) initialize it (form2) with a settings in a file. If that is correct, then you cannot use a static method because what you are setting up is specific to that instantiation.  You will need to use Dilip's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing Form1 instance in the constructor of Form2

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to pass Form2 as argument in Form1.

Your error comes because Form2 is even not initialize when your Form1 is loaded when you execute your program.

So thr solution to this is you can create object of Form2 in Form1 as under:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.InitializeWithFile(StringA);
```

Or create static method in Form2:

```
public static void InitializeWithFile(string csFileName){//Your Code code}
```

and use it as under::

```
Form2.InitializeWithFile(StringA);
```

Comment: After using Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); frm2.InitializeWithFile(StringA); I am getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
     
            
        }

Comment: Again, I would suggest using your debugger. Put a breakpoint at `StreamReader hGetCommaDelimiterGrid=new StreamReader(csFileName);` and then look for places where object A creates an object B which in turn creates another object A, etc. or where you loop and increment a value (like `iRow++;`). Also, I would pay special attention to the line `bReadingFile = Convert.ToBoolean(hGetCommaDelimiterGrid.ReadToEnd());` I'm guessing that doesn't do what you think it does. Reading the exception details may tell you more. Since I don't know what any of those other methods do, I can't comment further...

Comment: write method as frm2.InitializeWithFile(ref StringA);